# Correct syntax to determine User identity on Site.Master using ASP.NET Identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

I cannot determine the correct syntax to determine the User identity on a Site.Master code behind page.

Microsoft says:

Display Logged in User Name: The Microsoft ASP.NET Identity Framework has added extension methods on  System.Security.Principal.IIdentity that allows you to get the  UserName and UserId for the logged in User. These extension methods are defined in the  Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core assembly. These extension methods are the replacement for  HttpContext.User.Identity.Name.

While this may assist experienced coders, I would appreciate the correct coding to replace:

```
HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Administrator")
```

Comment: Do you have a `Administrator` role define in your db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Microsoft.AspNetIdentity.Core you can use

```
 private UserManager<TenantUser> usermanager= new UserManager<TenantUser>(new UserStore<TenantUser>(_dbContext));
 bool isUserInRole = usermanager.IsInRole(Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.GetUserId(), "Administrator");
```

Comment: To expand: I'm using a Web-Forms project with the standard template.  Tread,CurrentPrincipal.Identity.GetUserId() returns Null.  I've also determined that User.Identity.GetUserId() returns userId when used on a web page that Inherits from System.Web.UI.Page however User... is not recognised on the Site Master as it inherits from MasterPage.  Any further assistance appreciated.

Comment: Solved, Nilesh's answer was the solution.  In my testing I did not login thus the user was null.  Code for this and problem solved.  Thanks